# Turn INSERT statement into UPDATE with multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

How do I turn this `INSERT` statement into an `UPDATE` Statement using MYSQL?  The table `filmInfo` references table `actorsInfo` with foreign key `id_actor` for `actorsInfo.id`.

Probably a better way to do this but this is what I have for now.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO filmInfo (filmTitle, filmRole, filmDirector, id_actor)
VALUES
('$_POST[filmTitle]','$_POST[filmRole]','$_POST[filmDirector]', 
( select id FROM actorsInfo WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'))";
```

Here is my query that works.

```
$query="SELECT filmTitle, filmRole, filmDirector, idfilm FROM filmInfo, actorsInfo
WHERE (actorsInfo.id = filmInfo.id_actor) AND email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
```

I tried this but `UPDATE` doesn't work:

```
$sql= "Update filmInfo  join actorsInfo 
ON actorsInfo.id = filmInfo.id_actor
Set 
filmTitle = '$filmTitle',
filmRole = '$filmRole',
filmDirecto = '$filmDirector'
WHERE (actorsInfo.id = afillInfo.id_actor) AND email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
```

Please help!

Comment: why are you using where actorsInfo.id = afillInfo.id_actor if you already have a join

Comment: I don't believe "doesn't work" is a standard MySQL or PHP error message. And it's certainly not a good descriptor of what's going wrong. Am I to understand that executing your query causes your coffee pot to start singing the ABC song?

Comment: What's `afillInfo`? There's no such table mentioned in the query. You don't need to repeat the `ON` condition in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$sql= "Update filmInfo  join actorsInfo 
ON actorsInfo.id = filmInfo.id_actor
Set 
filmTitle = '$filmTitle',
filmRole = '$filmRole',
filmDirecto = '$filmDirector'
WHERE email = '$_SESSION[email]'";
```

You were referencing `afillInfo.id_actor` in the `WHERE`, but there was no such table mentioned in thequery. All joining conditions should be in `ON` clauses.